# Does LOL run in fullscreen on first start

Tags: league-of-legends

Long story short, I want to start LOL in windowed mode and NOT fullscreen.  I just don't like fullscreen tabs.  Will LOL start in windowed mode by default or will I have to change it?  Ty

Comment: Tangentially related, you can resize the client with `Ctrl Plus` and `Ctrl Minus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The League of Legends **client** starts in windowed mode. It's from there that you can access the player shop, friend lists and it's where you pick what kind of game you want to play.

The **match screen** is by default in fullscreen, but you're able to change that in the Video Options during a match. When that's done LoL's matches should start in windowed mode.

Best way to change is to start a custom game alone and change there, so you don't risk getting put behind in an actual match

Comment: Wow.. I never knew LOL was so complex.  You know, funny story.  I'm taking a Game Dev class and I kept feeling bad that all my classmates were playing LOL and I wasn't, so.. here I am XD.  Thanks for the help anyways :D

Comment: It's not **that** complex. At least in this matter. It's just that the Client (where you do everything save for playing the game) has no need to be in fullscreen. The game itself is, as most games nowadays are. And good luck =)

Comment: The new client has been adding _In-Game_ options to the client's settings menu recently, so I'm assuming it will be possible in the future to change the video options from the Client. But currently it is not possible so as you've mentioned a custom game is the best option.

Comment: @Aequitas Yeah, those have been in demand for a long time, but it's a lot of work for Riot, so we've been waiting, often impatiently.